# ¿como conectar mi aplicación rails desde ubuntu a una base de datos sql server alojada en un servidor?

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

¿Necesito conectar mi aplicación rails a una base de datos sql server que se encuentra alojada en el servidor de la empresa, ya instale las gemas

```
gem 'tiny_tds' gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
```

Instale además `gem install deprecated`

Y en el yml(en el host supongo que debo de colocar el ip del servidor):

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlserver
  host: basddatos.dyndns.org
  username: zu
  password: pass
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: Basdatos_2016
```

A la hora de correr el servidor rails me manda el siguiente mensaje:

> TinyTds::Error Server name not found in configuration files

¿Qué podría faltarme?

Comment: ... asumo que esos datos de conexión no son los reales

Comment: Hola @Alter, no por seguridad, pero el Host es bastante parecido a ese

Answer (score 1):

Veo unos errores:

- `Host`, `Username` y `Password` deberían ser sólo con minúsculas.
- Tal cual dices, en `host` debes colocar la ip o el dominio del servidor, no así `http://` que indica el protocolo de comunicación a usar que no es para nada por el cual se comunica una conexión de SQL Server. Debería ir solamente `basddatos.dyndns.org`.

Comment: listo @Alter gracias ya actualice, porfa revisa el código de la descripción para ver si esta bien. ahora me dice: "Server name not found in configuration files"

Comment: @AlexanderMarcano hace años que no uso dyndns, pero no se si también redirecciona otros puertos aparte de los de tipo http/https. Prueba agregando el puerto al yml con `port: 1433` o el que esté configurado en sql server. ¿Has probado que tienes acceso al servidor?¿Te has conectado con un cliente de base de datos?

Comment: Agradezco muchísimo tu ayuda @AlterLagos ya coloque el puerto pero me sigue diciendo lo mismo "Server name not found in configuration files". Respecto a lo que dices, ¿como podría probar que tengo acceso al servidor y como podría conectarme con un cliente de base de datos?

Comment: me muestra el mismo error TinyTds::Error missing :host option if no :dataserver given

Comment: ahora me muestra este error  TinyTds::Error Server name not found in configuration files

Comment: Desconozco para que es la opción dataserver, ya que nunca he usado sql server. yo uso como cliente dbvisualizer, aunque imagino debe haber otros más enfocados en sal server. Si tampoco puedes conectarte desde ahí, entonces el problema es de la configuración/acceso a tu servidor, no de tu código

Comment: el error del dataserver ya no me lo esta dando, ahora me da este error TinyTds::Error Server name not found in configuration files

Comment: ¿como puedo probar que tengo acceso al servidor?

Comment: Y que pasó con dbvisualizer? Si no quieres usarlo, entonces busca información de otros clientes para bd o como conectarse a un servidor sql server, debe estar lleno de información en internet de como hacerlo